# django on nginx + uwsgi / static files don't show

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

So I want to run django on nginx with uwsgi. I installed everything, changed the ALLOWED_HOSTS and STATIC_ROOT in the settings.py and ran "collectstatic". With the terminal I can see that the admin-static-files were put exactly where I wanted them to be put. Yet I don't see the static files when I go to domainxy.de/admin . After my the installation I did this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/uwsgi/sites
sudo nano /etc/uwsgi/sites/mysite.ini
```

with

```
####mysite.ini####
[uwsgi]
project = mysite
uid = root
base = /%(uid)
chdir = %(base)/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application
master = true
processes = 5
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

and

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service
```

with

```
###uwsgi.service####
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown root:www-data /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf
```

with

```
####mysite.conf####
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domainxy.de www.domainxy.de xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static {
        root /root/mysite/;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/mysite.sock;
    }
}
```

and

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl start uwsgi
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
```

Where did I make the mistake? I did change the folders in "mysite.conf" multiple times but nothing helped so far. Thanks for helping. Don't judge me that I am a newbie and also not that I used the root-user for simplifying here.

Edit: my django-project is in /root/mysite/ and the settings.py is

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

Comment: Could you show us your `settings.py`? You probably have your `location /static` entry pointing to the wrong target direction. 

I can really recommend the article by Michal Karzynski, in case you are looking for a tutorial: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Comment: I edited the post and added the settings.py entries.

Comment: Can you add `try_files $uri $uri/ =444;` in your `location /static` block? Also when you static files don't  show, do they give 404 in or something else? I have added 444 here so that you know the location is being tested properly

Comment: doesn't work either. that way it doesn't even show domainxy.de/admin anymore as if there was no connection at all. Without it I get an "403 Forbidden - nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)" if I try access domainxy.de/static/ or any of the files in it.

Comment: That's pretty risky! You are exposing your python project and should be able to access e.g. your `manage.py` via http://yourdomain.com/static/manage.py. This happens because you are pointing your `location /static` entry to the root of your project, but not to the static folder. According to your information, you should change `location /static { root /root/mysite/; }` to `location /static { root /root/mysite/static; }`. Make sure, you have some files in your `static` folder and try to access it afterwards via http://yoursite.com/static/styles.css

Comment: doesn't work either.